# Change Android default notification sound based on time

Tags: android-notifications

I was wondering if it is possible to programmatically change the default notification sound on an Android phone based on what time it is.  For instance, I would like the default notification sound to change to Silent after 11PM and then back to a sound at 8AM.  I have a working knowledge of Java, but have never done any Android development.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going too much into detail, I would approach this problem by first creating an [AlarmService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) which will run periodically and change default Ringtone according to your desired time of the day via [RingtoneManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#setActualDefaultRingtoneUri%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.net.Uri%29)

AlarmManager setting up periodical invocations of "RingToneChanger.class" ,  something like this:

```
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
```

Then within triggered RingToneChanger.class, ringtone can be changed like this:

```
if(isNoon) {
   RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Context context, RingtoneManager. TYPE_NOTIFICATION , Uri lunchtimeNotificationSound);
} else {
   RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Context context, RingtoneManager. TYPE_NOTIFICATION , Uri defaultNotificationsound);
}
```

Hope it helps. else please don't hesitate to ask.